# Do on death triggers still function if they have been removed by an aura?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

I have a [Wurmcoil Engine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wurmcoil%20Engine). My opponent casts [Reprobation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reprobation) on it, making it a 0/1 Coward without any abilities.

If the Wurmcoil Engine dies, do I get the tokens it would generate? The specific text on the card says “put into the graveyard from the battlefield” - so does it enter the graveyard as a Wurmcoil Engine or as a Coward due to the Reprobation?

Comment: Note that Wurmcoil Engine does _not_ use the phrasing "put into the graveyard from the battlefield" any more; the Oracle text is "When Wurmcoil Engine dies" and the Oracle text is all that matters.

Comment: In this case, the different Oracle text doesn't make a difference in the outcome. The rules define "dies" to mean "is put into a graveyard from the battlefield" (700.4).